# Microfocus and MQ connection

Tags: ibm-mq, microfocus

Currently Microfocus server and IBM MQ are hosted in different servers and linked by MQSERVER environmental variable in Microfocus.
What configuration need to be changed in Microfocus to connect to IBM MQ hosted on same server?

I tried changing the MQSERVER variable to new server details, but it failed due to 2538 unable to find mq host.

Comment: 2538 means host not available.  If your MQ server is running on the local server, then you should be able to set the `host(port)` part of MQSERVER to `localhost(port)`.  You need to ensure that the LISTENER on that port referenced is running on the queue manager.

Comment: @JoshMc thank you. I changed the host value to LOCALHOST and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code does not provide any of the connection details, which given you are using `MQSERVER` environment variable, suggests it does not; then you can switch from a client connection to a local bindings connection by:-

- Removing the `MQSERVER` environment variable
- (Optionally) setting the `MQ_CONNECT_TYPE` environment variable to `LOCAL`

Comment: Assuming MQ v7.1 or later.